# Python regex re.sub() is not matching and replacing as expected

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The following regex isn't replacing substrings as expected.

I've tried running the code with the following modifications (one at a time, of course) all with no luck:

- Utilizing list comprehensions (current)
- Using a traditional for loop
- Adding the regex result back to the iterator itself
- Appending the regex result to a new list
- Checked the type of 'name' (it's a string)
- Utilized (copied) code format from another regex in my notebook that is currently working
- Put the regex into regex101.com to verify that it's functioning (you can see the regex and data I'm using [here](https://regex101.com/r/SVKyjN/4)
- Adding/removing the raw string indicators preceding the regex and substitution patterns

## names is a list of strings

```
reg_pattern = r"(?!\\s)(\\W[^\\W,]+)(?!,) and\\s([^ ]+ )([^ ]+)"
sub_pattern = r"\\1 \\3 \\2\\3"
cleaned_names = []
cleaned_names = [re.sub(reg_pattern, sub_pattern, name) for name in names]
```

The goal can be seen in the link above (particularly in the 'substitution' section at the bottom of that page), but ultimately, I need to append group3 of the regex to the end of group1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe, you're trying to `re.sub` the couples names, for which you can likely write some expression similar to:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+and\s+(.*)([A-Z]\S*)
```

if you are not having edge cases, if you do then, you'd probably want to modify the char classes, `[A-Z]`, and add those other chars, in there.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XbnKrk/1)

#### Test

```
import re

l = ['George Rosario, Ali Jones, Barbara Boll, and Lindsay McKelvoy', 'Jan and Edgar Adelman', 'Bill Mack and Les Lieberman', 'Dr. Susan Muehle-Bussel, Ray Morales, and Dr. Samuel Barker', 'Dan Barroso and Emily High', 'Cassie and George Sorenson', 'Tom Scott and Mark Smith', 'The scene at IDEAL School & Academy’s 10th\xa0Annual Gala.',
     'Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish Iervolino, and Ron Iervolino', 'Chuck Grodin', 'Diana Rosario, Ali Sussman, Sarah Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay Macbeth', 'Kelly and Tom Murro', 'Udo Spreitzenbarth', 'Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton', 'Barbara Loughlin, Dr. Gerald Loughlin, and Debbie Gelston', 'Julianne Michelle']

e = r'([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+and\s+(.*)([A-Z]\S*)'

l_out = []
for names in l:
    if re.match(e, names):
        l_out.append(re.sub(e, r'\1 \3 and \2\3', names))
    else:
        l_out.append(names)

print(l_out)
```

#### Output

> ['George Rosario, Ali Jones, Barbara Boll, and Lindsay McKelvoy', 'Jan
>   Adelman and Edgar Adelman', 'Bill Mack and Les Lieberman', 'Dr. Susan
>   Muehle-Bussel, Ray Morales, and Dr. Samuel Barker', 'Dan Barroso and
>   Emily High', 'Cassie Sorenson and George Sorenson', 'Tom Scott and
>   Mark Smith', 'The scene at IDEAL School & Academy’s 10th\xa0Annual
>   Gala.', 'Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish
>   Iervolino, and Ron Iervolino', 'Chuck Grodin', 'Diana Rosario, Ali
>   Sussman, Sarah Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay
>   Macbeth', 'Kelly Murro and Tom Murro', 'Udo Spreitzenbarth', 'Ron
>   Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton',
>   'Barbara Loughlin, Dr. Gerald Loughlin, and Debbie Gelston', 'Julianne
>   Michelle']

---

Or you can try

```
import re

l = ['George Rosario, Ali Jones, Barbara Boll, and Lindsay McKelvoy', 'Jan and Edgar Adelman', 'Bill Mack and Les Lieberman', 'Dr. Susan Muehle-Bussel, Ray Morales, and Dr. Samuel Barker', 'Dan Barroso and Emily High', 'Cassie and George Sorenson', 'Tom Scott and Mark Smith', 'The scene at IDEAL School & Academy’s 10th\xa0Annual Gala.',
     'Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish Iervolino, and Ron Iervolino', 'Chuck Grodin', 'Diana Rosario, Ali Sussman, Sarah Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay Macbeth', 'Kelly and Tom Murro', 'Udo Spreitzenbarth', 'Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton', 'Barbara Loughlin, Dr. Gerald Loughlin, and Debbie Gelston', 'Julianne Michelle']

e = r'([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+and\s+(.*)([A-Z]\S*)'

l_out = []
for names in l:
    if re.match(e, names):
        l_out.append(re.sub(e, r'\1 \3', names))
        l_out.append(re.sub(e, r'\2\3', names))
    else:
        l_out.append(names)

print(l_out)
```

#### Output

> ['George Rosario, Ali Jones, Barbara Boll, and Lindsay McKelvoy', 'Jan
>   Adelman', 'Edgar Adelman', 'Bill Mack and Les Lieberman', 'Dr. Susan
>   Muehle-Bussel, Ray Morales, and Dr. Samuel Barker', 'Dan Barroso and
>   Emily High', 'Cassie Sorenson', 'George Sorenson', 'Tom Scott and Mark
>   Smith', 'The scene at IDEAL School & Academy’s 10th\xa0Annual Gala.',
>   'Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish Iervolino, and
>   Ron Iervolino', 'Chuck Grodin', 'Diana Rosario, Ali Sussman, Sarah
>   Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay Macbeth', 'Kelly
>   Murro', 'Tom Murro', 'Udo Spreitzenbarth', 'Ron Iervolino, Trish
>   Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton', 'Barbara Loughlin, Dr.
>   Gerald Loughlin, and Debbie Gelston', 'Julianne Michelle']

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/L2BUks/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/L2BUks/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Unfortunately, this output doesn't match what I'm looking for.  An example is 'Jan Edgar and Edgar Adelman' in your output.  This should be 'Jan Adelman and Edgar Adelman' (or better yet, 'Jan Adelman', 'Edgar Adelman'.  

Additionally, if I try this with the entire dataset (not singling out those cases I'm interested in).  I tried this with my regex function, and I still get the original list back (no changes).

Comment: this appears to do the trick!  Thanks!  What was your intuition that led you to the solution?